# Dict obj has no attribute count when finding degree of a graph

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm

I am implementing a graph class and would like to write a function that calculates the degree of a given vertex. I'm getting a type error in my degree function, because I'd like to use .count to count the number of instances of vertex v.

My graph is represented as {a:{b:c}}
where a and b are a vertex connected to each other, and c is the weight of the edge

Given:

```
{0: {1: 5, 2: 5}, 2: {3: 5}, 1: {3: 5}, 4: {1: 5, 3: 5}}
```

Vertex 1 has a degree of 3 because it's connected to vertex 0,3 and 4.

My class:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        """
        Constructor
        :param n: Number of vertices
        """
        self.order = n
        self.size = 0
        self.vertex = {}

    def insert_edge(self, u, v, w): #works fine
        if u in self.vertex and v < self.order:
            if not v in self.vertex[u]:
                self.vertex[u][v] = w
                self.size += 1
        elif u not in self.vertex and u < self.order and v < self.order:
            self.vertex[u] = {}
            self.vertex[u][v] = w
            self.size += 1
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def degree(self, v):
        adj_vertices =  self.vertex[v]
        degree = len(adj_vertices) + adj_vertices.count(v) #ERROR in .count
        return degree
```

Main function:

```
def main():
    g = Graph(5)
    g.insert_edge(0,1,5)
    g.insert_edge(0,2,5)
    g.insert_edge(2,3,5)
    g.insert_edge(1,3,5)
    g.insert_edge(4,1,5)
    g.insert_edge(4,3,5)

    print(g.vertex) #print the graph
    print(g.degree(1)) #error, should print out 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the logic of your degree function as follows.
I am checking if the key equals the vertex v, I count how many items are in that dictionary, or if in the sub-dictionary, how many of them contain the vertex v as a dictionary

```
def degree(self, v):
    degree = 0
    for key, value in self.vertex.items():
        if key == v:
            degree += len(value)
        elif v in value:
            degree += 1
    return degree
```

Once I run this, I get

```
print(g.vertex)
print(g.degree(0))
print(g.degree(1))
print(g.degree(2))
print(g.degree(3))
print(g.degree(4))
#{0: {1: 5, 2: 5}, 2: {3: 5}, 1: {3: 5}, 4: {1: 5, 3: 5}}
#2
#3
#2
#3
#2
```

Comment: vertex 0 should return 2 instead of 1 though. It's connected to both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

`.count()` is a method on lists, not dictionaries. In this case you want to find all the other vertexes that have v as an element in them.

```
def degree(self, v):
        adj_vertices =  self.vertex[v]
        others_connecting = [other for other in self.vertex.values() if v in other]
        degree = len(adj_vertices) + len(others_connecting)
        return degree
```

Here's my approach, self.vertex.values() gives you a list of dictionary objects, and the list comprehension filters to make the resulting list only contain other vertices that connect.

Comment: There's an issue if you want to find the degree of 3. Although it is not a key, 3 is connected to 1, 2 and 4. If you try 3 it will give a KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

You represent a graph as dict of dicts and try to call count of the inner dict, which is not a function of a general dict. Why you not simply return

```
def degree(self, v):
    return len(self.vertex[v])
```

and may you want to take a look at the package networkx.

Answer (score 0):

```
graph = {0: {1: 5, 2: 5}, 2: {3: 5}, 1: {3: 5}, 4: {1: 5, 3: 5}}
v = 1
len (graph [v]) + reduce (lambda x, y: x + (1 if v in graph [y] else 0), graph, 0)
```

Outputs `3` for me.

**Explanation**

`1 if v in graph [y] else 0` evaluates to `1` if there is edge from `y` to `v` in graph, and to `0` otherwise.

`reduce (lambda x, y: x + (1 if v in graph [y] else 0), graph, 0)` evaluates to the number of vertices that have edges from them to `v`.

`len (graph [v])` evaluates to the number of edges from `v` to other vertices.

and the whole expression calculates number of edges from `v` to other vertices plus number of vertices that have edges from then to `v`, i.e. calculates degree of `v`.